# What do I do if my brakes keep squeaking when I press on them? Do I use lubricant or what?

Tags: tire, brakes

It’s really annoying in public places when I’m trying to stop my bike. Please explain

Comment: You should never lubricate your brakes

Answer (score 8):

Answer: **NO**

**NEVER** lubricate the friction surfaces of your brake system under any circumstances.  There is NO time where this makes sense, ever.

---

Do check the duplicate question for answers on how to reduce squeal.

Or embrace it - I had some canti brakes that would make hideously loud noises under hard braking, but under gentle braking they were silent.  After a while I realised that is really a feature, cos hard braking squeals is like a car horn and alerts people to a possible danger.

Comment: Adding this as an answer so future searchers are more likely to see it, rather than expecting them to check the duplicate question.

Comment: +! for answering the non dupe and safety related question "should I lubricate my brakes?"

Comment: The idea of duplicates is for users to go there. By not adding this to the duplicate you dilute the duplicate.  Those users have no way of knowing to go here.

Comment: When I cycled as a teenager I was happy that the brakes squealed. They were louder than the asthmatic bell anyway. ;-)

Comment: @Paparazzi "brake squeal" is the dupe, and "should I lubricate my brakes" was the part of the question addressed by this answer.

Comment: Was already the top comment.   No big deal.